# I am not able to create an Excel workbook with openpyxl if I write the code in a Tkinter class under a definition

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, openpyxl

I am wondering why I am not able to create an excel workbook inside a Tkinter class?

I write the exact same code in a regular script, but whenever I put the code into a bigger script with definitions and want to add it in a tkinter class then the excel workbook is not created. Does anyone know how to work around this?

Code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb =Workbook(r"C:\Myfile.xlsx")
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = "First"
ws2 = wb.create_sheet("Second")
ws3 = wb.create_sheet("Third")
ws4 = wb.create_sheet("Fourth")
ws5 = wb.create_sheet("Fifth")

wb.save(r"C:\Myfile.xlsx")
```

When I run this alone the excel file is made, but when I put it into a class it does not.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
NORM_FONT  = ("Verdana", 10)
SMALL_FONT = ("Verdana", 8)

current_dir = os.getcwd()


class Gui(Tk):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Tk.wm_title(self, "Program")

        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.geometry("350x500")

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)

        self.frames[StartPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = Label(self, text="Program", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        self.buttons()
        self.program = ""

    def runanalyze0(self, *args):
        try:
            wb =Workbook(r"C:\Myfile.xlsx")
            ws1 = wb.active
            ws1.title = "First"
            ws2 = wb.create_sheet("Second")
            ws3 = wb.create_sheet("Third")
            ws4 = wb.create_sheet("Fourth")
            ws5 = wb.create_sheet("Fifth")

            wb.save(r"C:\Myfile.xlsx")
       finally:
            self.finishpop()

     def finishpop(msg):

        messagebox.showinfo("Done","Done")


    def buttons(self):

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        button = Button(self, text="Xlsx file", command=self.runanalyze0())
        button.place(x=50, y=150)

        e1 = Entry(self, bd=5)
        e1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        e1.insert(0, "{}".format(current_dir))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Gui()
    app.mainloop()

Traceback:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Myfile.xlsx'
```

Working in Python 3.4.1. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Instead of `r"C:Myfile.xlsx"`, use the full path to the file and see if that helps.

Comment: If it's on Windows then the path is probably `c:\Myfile.xlsx`. Best to use `os.path` to create paths.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong for the question, it is correct in my real code. I'll try using os.path, but it is still strange that I am able to create the xlsx file when isolating the code, but not when I put it into the rest of the tkinter code.

Comment: Could you please modify your code example so that we can run it to reproduce the error that you're getting? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, I think you are able to run it now.

Comment: @Pexe Thanks for the update. One other question: are you absolutely certain that your first code example (the script) runs without errors and creates a new Excel file? Because it would appear to me that the variable `ws` that you're using in the last line has not been created anywhere before yet, and therefore this line shouldn't be possible for Python to execute (unless perhaps a variable `ws` was created before in other code not shown here?).

Comment: This should be `wb.save(...` instead of `ws.save(...`.